# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (91:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am testing angular map api for tracking place in a search box field on Ionic 3.

I don't know how to solve this problem "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (91:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." Apreciate any help please.

Ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

//Import for Search box
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";
import { } from 'googlemaps';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

//declare var google: any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html'
})
export class MapPage {
    public latitude: number;
    public longitude: number;
    public searchControl: FormControl;
    public zoom: number;

    @ViewChild("search")
    public searchElementRef;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone)  {
      this.zoom = 4;
      this.latitude = 39.8282;
      this.longitude = -98.5795;

      //create search FormControl
      this.searchControl = new FormControl();

      //set current position
      this.setCurrentPosition();

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      //set google maps defaults
      this.zoom = 4;
      this.latitude = 39.8282;
      this.longitude = -98.5795;

      //create search FormControl
      this.searchControl = new FormControl();

      //set current position
      this.setCurrentPosition();

      //load Places Autocomplete
      this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
          let nativeHomeInputBox = 
  document.getElementById('txtHome').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
          let autocomplete = new 
  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(nativeHomeInputBox, {
              types: ["address"]
          });
          autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
              this.ngZone.run(() => {
                  //get the place result
                  let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = 
   autocomplete.getPlace();

                  //verify result
                  if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === 
                       null) {
                      return;
                  }

                  //set latitude, longitude and zoom
                  this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                  this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                  this.zoom = 12;
              });
          });
      });
    }

    private setCurrentPosition() {
        if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                this.zoom = 12;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

HTML file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
      <!--<button ion-button menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>-->
    <ion-title>Kokua</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content padding>
  <!-- "no borders" "transparent" "fullscreen="true"" "<div #map id="map"> 
  </div>" -->
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Enter Address</ion-label>
      <ion-input id="txtHome" type="text"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" 
  [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
      <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: you kept empty object for import { } from 'googlemaps';

Comment: This was a test that I did, but if I remove the import the error continues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was unexpected and simple. I just clean the cash and the trash of my code, like comments and imports never used. Then the code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, not in a .html but in the .ts file.

The "problem" was that I'd a very long comment  /*    */ to keep the entire old version of that .ts file. The comment was fine, with no one part outside of it; but very long.

Just deleting that very long comment solved that.